# How to pass a parameter to controller action from my view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an action from my view passing a paremeter value
that's my code

```
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "RelatoriosConsolidados")';
```

to pass some parameter I can do this

```
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "RelatoriosConsolidados", 
                          new { param1 = "Value"})';
```

but I cant get a value from a datepicker

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("#datepicker")
          .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
          .Min(new DateTime(2012, 7, 1))

          .Value(Model.dataInicial)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })

   function change() 
   {
    var x = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd');
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "RelatoriosConsolidados",
     new { data = x })';
   }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us your `Index` action method?

Comment: var x is a javascript variable, which is running client-side. Url.Action is happening on the server before the client script ever runs.

Comment: exactly, how can I get the datepicker value?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the url of action as conventional MVC route `{controller}/{Action}/{Id}`. And then get the passed parameter (with same parameter name) in your action. My implementation would be something like this:

**View.cshtml**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // create DatePicker from input HTML element
            $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

            $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                alert($('#datepicker').val());
                var data = $('#datepicker').val();
                window.location.href = "/Home/Contact/" + data;
            });
       });
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Contact(string data)
        {
           //do something with 'data'
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
```